# SSIS executable expression logging

Tags: logging, ssis

I have a DataFlow Task which I assign a sql statement through the expression editor, for the `[DataReader Source].[SqlCommand]` property.

This sql statement contains variables which change at run time.
so for debugging purposes; how can I log the SqlCommand Value at run time?

I know that I can log simple variables in a script task as `Dts.Variables["YourVariable"].Value` but I wonder how task properties - like the one above - can be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will have access to those properties within the package. For this reason, my preference is to always have expressions on task be a straight variable assignment. Otherwise, debugging and logging are far harder than they need to be.

Comment: I get this point, but in my case I had too many variables and was suspecting that i have a problem w/ varaibles not being re-evaluated.